# prevent gcc from removing an unused variable

Tags: c, gcc

In our source files we usually have a version string like that:

```c
static const char srcvers[] = "VERSION/foo.c/1.01/09.04.15";
```

When that string isn't optimized away, it's quite useful in certain cases, as one can determine the version of each source file linked to an executable by simply calling `strings a.out | grep VERSION`.

Unfortunately it **is** optimized away by gcc (using '-O'). So my question is, is there a simple way (a compiler switch would be great) to make gcc keep that variable (its name is always the same) without switching off any other optimizations.

**Edit**

What, in my opinion, makes the question different from [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-compiler-optimization-on-a-small-piece-of-code), is that I'm was hoping to find a solution for which I wouldn't have to touch thousands of source files.

Comment: What about add `-v` option on all your binary displaying this var ?

Comment: Maybe try tricking `gcc` into thinking the variable is used (something like `strlen(srcvers);`)?

Comment: Tried to make it `volatile`? It should work: `volatile static const char srcvers[] = "VERSION/foo.c/1.01/09.04.15";`

Comment: @Ôrel do you mean `a.out -v`? that would work for one source file only, and we do that already. I would like to get information about all files linked together

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent compiler optimization on a small piece of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083482/how-to-prevent-compiler-optimization-on-a-small-piece-of-code)

Comment: @Drew it's thousands of source files (I'm serious, really), so that was to much effort vs. profit

Comment: @Sam right, that works. Although it doesn't help for all the files unchanged, it's at least a good idea for the future. Thanks

Comment: in your build system, generate a file with all you version and display it with -v

Comment: You could just remove the word static.  Since it is not static, it must be public so the compiler will not remove it.  May be thousands of files but you could use sed to do them.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I added the answer which takes into account your desire **not** to modify source files.

Comment: Try `-Dsrcvers='volatile __attribute__((used)) srcvers`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `__attribute__((used))` gcc (also works in clang) specific (I see that the question is tagged `gcc`) attributes for this:

> This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is not referenced. This is useful, for example, when the function is referenced only in inline assembly.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Demo:

```
$ cat a.c
static const char srcvers[] __attribute__((used)) = "VERSION/foo.c/1.01/09.04.15";
$ gcc -O3 -c a.c
$ strings a.o
VERSION/foo.c/1.01/09.04.15
```

You can use some `#if`s and `#define`s to make this terser and also compile on compilers which don't support this extension.

Comment: Although the documentation excerpt describes usage of this attribute with functions, the same attribute can also be used with variables, provided they have static storage (as in this case).

Comment: great idea, thank you. But the ideal solution for was one where I wouldn't need to modify every source file.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt - you can do something similar with a linker script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827157/what-does-keep-mean-in-a-linker-script

Comment: I finally decided to accept your answer although it's not quite what I hoped for but it seems that what I hoped for doesn't exist and this is the second best thing to do. Thanks to all

Comment: Note that attribute((used)) cannot be used on locals, and gcc 6 has gotten smarter about optimizing away locals that you don't appear to be using.

Comment: Is there a similar mechanism for MSVC? Or does that compiler never remove unused static variables in a static library?

Comment: ```__attribute__((used))``` did not work for me with a global variable (the documentation does imply it only works on functions) (arm-none-eabi gcc 7), but putting the symbol in a different section via ```__attribute__((section(".data")))``` did work. This is presumably because the linker's is only able to strip symbols when they are given their own section via `-fdata-sections`. I do not like it, but it worked.

Comment: @szmoore Unfortunately specifying section doesn't work as you describe for AVR (GCC 5.4.0). Object will not be placed in `.data` (why though?) and linker flushes the unused section out. After reading all I can find online, the only way to keep an object is to somehow actually use it... I feel like this is much too hard, and that it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Tammi Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827157/what-does-keep-mean-in-a-linker-script

Comment: @Tammi If there's not too many symbols, adding a `-u` flag for the linker might be useful. Since I wrote the comment, rather than re-using `.data`, I edit the linker script. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985290/how-to-prevent-linker-from-discarding-a-function/66170699#66170699 . Without messing with the linker, you are right (use the variable somehow).

Answer (score 5):

As I understand your question, you need to add version string to every object file without touching sources. It can be done using next way.

Create header file, for example `include/version.h`:

```c
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

static const char _ver[] __attribute__((used)) = "VERSION/foo.c/1.01/09.04.15";

#endif /* VERSION_H */
```

Then in your `Makefile` (or whatever your build system is) add next `gcc` flag:

```
CPPFLAGS += -include include/version.h
```

Of course it should be passed to `gcc`, e.g. like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(*).o -c $(*).c
```

Now you can observe your `_ver` string compiled to every object file:

```
$ objdump -DS src/main.o | grep _ver
```

Which will show you something like that:

```
Disassembly of section .rodata._ver:
00000000 <_ver>:
```

Comment: the version string is already there but are optimized away (and of course I need that one with dates like '03.01.01', some files are really old). But the idea wih `-include` smells a little bit like I could use it to solve the problem anyway. Thank you again

Comment: Ah, your source files have different versions, I see. Thought that version stands for project itself.

Comment: nope that would be too easy (in fact that's an additional information we already have, but somtimes you just need to be sure if a certain change in a file included by a library .. is linked or not)

Comment: Well, the best way to fix it then is to modify code in each source file (adding `__attribute__((used))`). It can be easily done with bash oneliner, using `find` and `sed` commands. Do you have something preventing you to do that?

Comment: yes of course, but I really want old files to remain literally old. Besides the files are checked in in an sccs based release control system (have I already mentioned 'old'?) but that would be solvable, of course.

Comment: I figured some way to do what you want, but it's kinda ugly and you are probably not gonna like it :) You can generate **new** source files before running compilation, adding `__attribute__((used))` to your version string, and then run build process using generated files. Right after build you can remove those generated files.

Comment: __attribute__((used)) only applies to functions. It is not a valid attribute for variables:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html, 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the variable as `volatile` can also help. That's why it is used in the first place, preventing any optimizations by the compiler regarding that variable.

Comment: It definitely helps; I have already checked. But again, this would mean touching each and every file :-(. Thanks anyway

Comment: Note that this is *implementation defined*. There is no guarantee that this will work, as standard only requires that `volatile` affects accesses to the variable. If variable is never used, compiler can remove it freely.

Comment: Yup, just to confirm @user694733 - just tried `volatile` in hopes to prevent removal/optimization of unused variable in a GCC C project, but it got optimized away anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that all the solutions require some kind of decoration of the version string in the source, it may help to define a macro containing all the necessary syntax and then use this macro in the source or header files whenever need:

```
#define SRCVERSION(file, version, data) static const char _ver[] __attribute__((used)) = "VERSION/" file "/" version "/" date;
```

Then in your source just put

```
SRCVERSION("foo.c", "1.01", "09.04.15")
```

The macro may be in a central project header file or on the compiler's command line.

That way, at least you do not have to touch all the source files again if you want to change something about the definition.

Note how the macro definition uses string concatenation to build the final version string.
Also it contains the final semicolon so you can remove everything by defining an empty macro if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned about `gcc` removing an unused `static char[]` variable. AFAIK, the compiler is right to do so.

Other answers provided suggestion to improve that. But you don't want to change the source code of thousands of files.

Then, you might perhaps change your build (e.g. some `Makefile`)  so that every  such source file using your trick (which is slightly wrong, as discussed here...) would not need to be changed. So you might [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) specifically. You want

```
 static const char _ver[] __attribute__((used));
```

(this is a declaration, not a definition) to be compiled before anything else. Put the line above in some `_declare_ver.h` file, and compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) `gcc -include _declare_ver.h` command (instead of `gcc`). If using `make` add

```
 CFLAGS += -include _declare_ver.h
```

in your `Makefile`.

BTW, that is a dirty trick. You should consider doing something better (following other answers).