# how to prevent linker from discarding a function?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, attributes

I have a function in my C code that is being called implicitly, and getting dumped by the linker. how can I prevent this phenomena?

I'm compiling using gcc and the linker flag -gc-sections, and I don't want to exclude the whole file from the flag. I tried using attributes: "used" and "externally_visible" and neither has worked.

```
void __attribute__((section(".mySec"), nomicromips, used)) func(){
...
}
```

on map file I can see that the function has compiled but didn't linked. am I using it wrong? is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "called _implicitly_"?

Comment: I don't know much about `__attribute__` but reading https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function%20Attributes makes me think that your syntax is wrong. Seems it should be. `void func() __attribute__ ((..)); void func() {…};`. Besides that it's unclear what you mean by "called implicit".

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what you are doing, what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Another link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: by implicitly I mean that I'm using the section address to call the function

Comment: the syntax is probably correct, because when I'm calling the function from a different  place in my code, the section and nomicromips attributes are working.

Comment: I want to approach the function using the section address, but when I doesn't call the function explicitly, the linker is discarding the function from the .elf file as it should, I expected that using the "used" attribute will force the linker to keep the function in the .elf file

Comment: @ronlandau You could take the address of the function in another object file in an acutally used part of code (i.e. `void *ptr = func`). This should help (albeit a bit hackish). Otherwise, you can always use a specific linker script to have detailed control over what you export

Comment: you need to add  `KEEP(*(.mySec))` in the linker script as well

Comment: is the linker script is the .ld file? where should I add it? the section is defined like this:  .mySec   : { } > memoryArea

Comment: There may be a command-line switch to tell the linker to behave as if there is a reference to a symbol. I am on mobile and cannot look it up immediately. Apple’s `ld` has it, but I am not sure about other versions. It is used for pulling object modules from a library in preparing intermediate files for later relinking, but it might work for ensuring a routine is retained in this way too.

Comment: The switch mentioned in my above comment is `-u`. Adding `-u func` to the `ld` command line tells the linker there is effectively a reference to `func`, so it is, at the start, an undefined symbol for which a definition must be provided.

Answer (score 10):

You are misunderstanding the [`used` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)

> used
>
> This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is not referenced...

i.e *the compiler* must emit the function definition even the function appears
to be unreferenced. The compiler will never conclude that a function is unreferenced
if it has external linkage. So in this program:

**main1.c**

```
static void foo(void){}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
$ gcc -c -O1 main1.c
```

No definition of `foo` is emitted at all:

```
$ nm main1.o
0000000000000000 T main
```

because `foo` is not referenced in the translation unit, is not external,
and so may be optimised out.

But in this program:

**main2.c**

```
static void __attribute__((used)) foo(void){}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

`__attribute__((used))` compels the compiler to emit the local definition:

```
$ gcc -c -O1 main2.c
$ nm main2.o
0000000000000000 t foo
0000000000000001 T main
```

But this does nothing to inhibit the *linker* from discarding a section
in which `foo` is defined, in the presence of `-gc-sections`, even if `foo` *is* external, if that section is unused:

**main3.c**

```
void foo(void){}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with function-sections:

```
$ gcc -c -ffunction-sections -O1 main3.c
```

The global definition of `foo` is in the object file:

```
$ nm main3.o
0000000000000000 T foo
0000000000000000 T main
```

But after linking:

```
$ gcc -Wl,-gc-sections,-Map=mapfile main3.o
```

`foo` is not defined in the *program*:

```
$ nm a.out | grep foo; echo Done
Done
```

And the function-section defining `foo` was discarded:

**mapfile**

```
...
...
Discarded input sections
 ...
 ...
 .text.foo      0x0000000000000000        0x1 main3.o
 ...
 ...
```

As per Eric Postpischil's comment, to force the *linker* to retain
an apparently unused function-section you must tell it to *assume* that the program
references the unused function, with linker option [`{-u|--undefined} foo`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options):

**main4.c**

```
void __attribute__((section(".mySec"))) foo(void){}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't tell it that:

```
$ gcc -c main4.c
$ gcc -Wl,-gc-sections main4.o
$ nm a.out | grep foo; echo Done
Done
```

`foo` is not defined in the program. If you do tell it that:

```
$ gcc -c main4.c
$ gcc -Wl,-gc-sections,--undefined=foo main4.o
$ nm a.out | grep foo; echo Done
0000000000001191 T foo
Done
```

it is defined. There's no use for attribute `used`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `-u` already mentioned here are two other ways to keep the symbol using GCC.

### Create a reference to it without calling it

This approach does not require messing with linker scripts, which means it will work for hosted programs and libraries using the operating system's default linker script.

However it varies with compiler optimization settings and may not be very portable.

For example, in GCC 7.3.1 with LD 2.31.1, you can keep a function without actually calling it, by calling another function on its address, or branching on a pointer to its address.

```
bool function_exists(void *address) {
    return (address != NULL);
}

// Somewhere reachable from main
assert(function_exists(foo));
assert(foo != NULL);  // Won't work, GCC optimises out the constant expression
assert(&foo != NULL);  // works on GCC 7.3.1 but not GCC 10.2.1
```

Another way is to create a `struct` containing function pointers, then you can group them all together and just check the address of the `struct`. I use this a lot for interrupt handlers.

### Modify the linker script to keep the section

If you are developing a hosted program or a library, then it's pretty tricky to change the linker script.

Even if you do, its not very portable, for example `gcc` on OSX does not actually use the GNU linker since OSX uses the Mach-O format instead of ELF.

Your code already shows a custom section though, so it's possible you are working on an embedded system and can easily modify the linker script.

```
SECTIONS {
    // ...
    .mySec {
        KEEP(*(.mySec));
    }
}
```