# Template-based self-registering factory with modern CMake build and source-drop-in detection

Tags: c++, cmake, factory

I am trying to set up a project structure fulfilling the following goals:

- an application needs to instantiate classes using a factory;
- classes instantiated by the factory have to be able to self-register to the factory;
- self-registration system usage should be very easy and foolproof.

This part of the problem is nicely solved by [Nir Friedman's blog post](http://www.nirfriedman.com/2018/04/29/unforgettable-factory/) on the topic (although I get compilation warnings when I'm using CLang, but that's another story).

Now, things get trickier when I try to apply this in the context of a project where people would like to add classes by simply dropping in sources. Building up on Nir's example (from which I stripped of a few things for convenience), I created the following layout (based on [Rafael Varago's post](https://code.egym.de/how-to-use-modern-cmake-for-an-app-lib-project-3c2ee6018cde)) [[see GitHub repository](https://github.com/momom4urice/cpp_factory_split)]:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main.cpp
└── libs
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── libanimal
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── animal
    │   │       └── Animal.h
    │   └── src
    │       ├── Cat.cpp
    │       └── Dog.cpp
    └── libfactory
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── include
            └── factory
                └── Factory.h
```

I tried to apply modern CMake practices when I wrote the `CMakeLists.txt` files, with one exception to be detailed below.

The `app` directory contains the application code which calls the factory:

```cpp
#include <animal/Animal.h>

int main() {
    auto x = Animal::make("Dog", 3);
    auto y = Animal::make("Cat", 2);
    x->makeNoise();
    y->makeNoise();
    return 0;
}
```

The `libs` directory contains two subdirs:

- `libfactory` contains the factory template code and is built as a header-only directory;
- `libanimal` contains the abstract class `Animal` and its associated factory, as well as the code for child classes; it is built as a static library, with a dependency to `libfactory`.

I want `libanimal` to have a sort of "compile-time plugin library" behavior: children of the `Animal` class would self-register to the `Animal` factory upon compilation. This purpose is served properly (on paper, at least) by Nir's method (`Animal.h`):

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <factory/Factory.h>

struct Animal : Factory<Animal, int> {
    Animal(Key) {}
    virtual void makeNoise() = 0;
};
```

Now, I want to combine this with the ability to centralize the child's code in a single cpp file, automatically detected by CMake when building the project. The advantage of this is that it allows to add and remove features extremely easily (just drop in a new file or delete it). For this purpose, I used a glob in `libanimal`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, thus violating modern CMake good practices. If there is a better way to achieve this, of course, I'd be happy to implement it. The code for `Dog.cpp` is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <animal/Animal.h>

class Dog : public Animal::Registrar<Dog> {
  public:
    Dog(int x) : m_x(x) {}

    void makeNoise() override { std::cerr << "Dog: " << m_x << "\n"; }

  private:
    int m_x;
};
```

When I build the project, everything seems to go fine, except for warnings I also get when I compile Nir's project (I get them with clang but not with gcc):

```
In file included from /Users/vincent/Documents/src/personal/sandboxes/cpp_factory_split/app/src/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /Users/vincent/Documents/src/personal/sandboxes/cpp_factory_split/libs/libanimal/include/animal/Animal.h:4:
In file included from /Users/vincent/Documents/src/personal/sandboxes/cpp_factory_split/libs/libfactory/include/factory/Factory.h:4:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:505:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:176:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:644:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2339:5: warning: delete called on 'Animal' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor [-Wdelete-abstract-non-virtual-dtor]
    delete __ptr;
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2652:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::default_delete<Animal>::operator()' requested here
      __ptr_.second()(__tmp);
      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2606:19: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Animal, std::__1::default_delete<Animal> >::reset' requested here
  ~unique_ptr() { reset(); }
                  ^
/Users/vincent/Documents/src/personal/sandboxes/cpp_factory_split/app/src/main.cpp:6:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Animal, std::__1::default_delete<Animal> >::~unique_ptr' requested here
    auto x = Animal::make("Dog", 3);
             ^
1 warning generated.
```

When I run the application, though, I get the following error:

- clang version:

```
/Users/vincent/Documents/src/personal/sandboxes/cpp_factory_split/build/app/app
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: unordered_map::at: key not found
```

- gcc version:

```
/Users/vincent/Documents/src/personal/sandboxes/cpp_factory_split/cmake-build-release-gcc/app/app
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  _Map_base::at
```

This seems to mean that the factory's table is empty, and I don't understand why.

## Questions

1. Did I misunderstand Nir's design?
2. If yes to 1., is anyone aware of a self-registration design which would involve as little maintenance as this one and would be suitable for my use case?
3. If no to 1., what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need virtual destructor for `Animal`. It is obligatory when defining interface in C++. Note that this dtor was added and the end of Nir's blog. Alternatively you can add it to `Factory` template.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `bool Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registered`
Note that this value is only referenced when it is initialized by:

```cpp
template <class Base, class... Args>
template <class T>
bool Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registered =
    Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registerT();
```

Now since this value is not used in code optimizer has removed it.
Since it was removed it is not initialized.
Since it was not initialized registration process was not performed.

This happen since you have spited code into multiple files and his example was placed in single source.

You have to do something which will prevent removal of `bool Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registered` by optimizer.

To prove my point, I've build your github project on Mac OS. The I've run this script:

```sh
nm app/Debug/app | awk '{print $NF}' | while read sym
do
    c++filt $sym | grep "Factory"
done
```

This outputs only that:

```
guard variable for Factory<Animal, int>::data()::s
Factory<Animal, int>::data()
std::__1::unique_ptr<Animal, std::__1::default_delete<Animal> > Factory<Animal, int>::make<int>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int&&)
Factory<Animal, int>::data()::s
```

Note there is no `registered` static fields or `Cat` or `Dog`. All this was removed by linker.

Script explanation

- `nm app/Debug/app` prints all symbols for `app`
- `awk '{print $NF}'` filter last columns (which provides mangled names)
- `while read sym` loop over mangled names
- `c++filt $sym` demangle names
- `grep "Factory"` show only things related to Factory.

Now when in `cat.cpp` I've added this:

```cpp
void dummy()
{
    std::cout << Animal::Registrar<Cat>::registered << '\n';
}
```

And invoked it in `main` creation of "Cat" is working ("Dog" keeps failing).

Scrip after that prints:

```
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::registered
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::registerT()
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::Registrar()
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::~Registrar()
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::~Registrar()
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::~Registrar()
typeinfo for Factory<Animal, int>
typeinfo for Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>
typeinfo name for Factory<Animal, int>
typeinfo name for Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>
vtable for Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>
Factory<Animal, int>::data()::s
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::registerT()::'lambda'(int)::operator()(int) const
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::registerT()::'lambda'(int)::operator std::__1::unique_ptr<Animal, std::__1::default_delete<Animal> > (*)(int)() const
Factory<Animal, int>::Registrar<Cat>::registerT()::'lambda'(int)::__invoke(int)
```

What is final prove that I'm right. Linker has noticed that symbols instantiating `Factory<Base, Args...>::Registrar<T>::registered` template are not reachable from `main` (there is only circular dependency) so it was removed.

[Here you can find answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990354/1387438) how to approach this problem in gcc (this doesn't work in clang - this attributes and linker flags are not present in clang), but as you can see it quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Nir Friedman's post is wrong. All self-registering tricks i've seen works more by "accident" (in other words your compiler gave you a free pass), rather than language rule.

C++ will keep order of instantiating globals only per compilation module. So if you've main file and some class in other file, globals from other file might be initialized at the first point "anything" from other file is used. Usually globals are still initialized before main, because compiler can't figure out, how properly delay (and there's little reason to delay static initialization anyway), but standard doesn't guarantee it. It works only because compiler is actually somewhat lazy.

On top of this he's using `demangle(typeid(T).name())`. This is also wrong - standard doesn't guarantee any valid content for `typeid(T).name()` call. It might be empty. It might also be removed (ever seen -no-rtti option to gcc? although at least you can manually remove that by yourself).

Don't use that kind of tricks, unless you're willing to stick to concrete compiler and it's concrete version. Those tricks are - at best - implementation defined.

EDIT:
"proper" (in other words standard conforming) way of solving this is some sort of macro and parser, which will parse your files, look for all classes, that has some special base class. This tool then writes initialization function, which you manually call from main and it's all good. You can use clang for this for example (scan whole project for classes and their's base classes and quickly build up such function).