# Prevent gcc from optimization/removal of variables when using -Wl,--gc-sections?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

I have an ARM project, where I would like to keep certain unused variables and their data, until the time they are used.

I have seen [prevent gcc from removing an unused variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545191/prevent-gcc-from-removing-an-unused-variable#comment95539989_29545417) :

> `__attribute__((used))` did not work for me with a global variable (the documentation does imply it only works on functions) (arm-none-eabi gcc 7), but putting the symbol in a different section via `__attribute__((section(".data")))` did work. This is presumably because the linker's is only able to strip symbols when they are given their own section via `-fdata-sections`. I do not like it, but it worked.

So, I tried this approach, but the variables were not kept - and I think this is because something in that project enables `-Wl,--gc-sections` during linking. Here is a minimal example showing what I've tried to do (basically the main file only refers to the header where the variables to be "kept" are declared as extern - and other than that, main program has does not use these variables; and then those same variables are defined in a separate .c file):

`test.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_opt.h"

const char greeting[] = "Hello World - am used";

int main(void) {
  printf("%s!\n", greeting);
  return 0;
}
```

`test_opt.h`

```c
#include <stdint.h>

extern const char mystring[];

struct MyStruct {
  uint16_t param_one;
  uint8_t param_two;
  unsigned char param_three[32];
};
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct_t;
extern const MyStruct_t mystruct;
```

`mystruct.c`

```c
#include "test_opt.h"

const char __attribute__((section(".MYSTRING"))) mystring[] = "Me, mystring, I am not being used";
const MyStruct_t __attribute__((section(".MYSTRUCT"))) mystruct = {
  .param_one = 65535,
  .param_two = 42,
  .param_three = "myStructer here",
};
```

---

### Test with usual MINGW64 gcc

Let's first try without `-Wl,--gc-sections`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g  mystruct.c test_opt.c -o test_opt.exe

$ strings ./test_opt.exe | grep -i 'mystring\|mystruct'
Me, mystring, I am not being used
*myStructer here
mystring
MyStruct
MyStruct_t
mystruct
mystruct.c
mystruct.c
mystruct.c
mystruct.c
mystring
mystruct
.MYSTRING
.MYSTRUCT
.MYSTRING
.MYSTRUCT
```

Clearly, variables and content are visible here.

Now let's try `-Wl,--gc-sections`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -Wl,--gc-sections mystruct.c test_opt.c -o test_opt.exe

$ strings ./test_opt.exe | grep -i 'mystring\|mystruct'
mystring
MyStruct
MyStruct_t
mystruct
mystruct.c
mystruct.c
mystruct.c
mystruct.c
mystring
mystruct
```

Apparently, here we still have some symbol debugging info left - but there are no sections, nor data being reported.

---

### Test with ARM gcc

Let's re-do same experiment with ARM gcc - first without `-Wl,--gc-sections`:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -g test_opt.c mystruct.c -o test_opt.elf -lc -lnosys

$ arm-none-eabi-strings ./test_opt.elf | grep -i 'mystring\|mystruct'
Me, mystring, I am not being used
*myStructer here
mystruct.c
MyStruct_t
MyStruct
mystruct
mystruct.c
mystring
mystruct.c
mystring
mystruct
.MYSTRING
.MYSTRUCT
```

Same as before, variables, content and section names are visible.

Now let's try with `-Wl,--gc-sections`:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -g -Wl,--gc-sections test_opt.c mystruct.c -o test_opt.elf -lc -lnosys

$ arm-none-eabi-strings ./test_opt.elf | grep -i 'mystring\|mystruct'
```

Note that, unlike the previous case, here there is neither any data content left, *nor* any debugging info/symbol names!

---

So, my question is: assuming that `-Wl,--gc-sections` is enabled in the project, and I otherwise do not want to remove it (because I like the functionality otherwise), can I somehow specify in code for some special variables, "keep these variables even if the are unused/unreferenced", in such a way that they are kept even with `-Wl,--gc-sections` enabled?

Note that adding `keep` to attributes, say:

```c
const char __attribute__((keep,section(".MYSTRING"))) mystring[] = "Me, mystring, I am not being used";
```

... and compiling with (or without) `-Wl,--gc-sections` typically results with compiler warning:

```
mystruct.c:3:1: warning: 'keep' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
    3 | const char __attribute__((keep,section(".MYSTRING"))) mystring[] = "Me, mystring, I am not being used";
      | ^~~~~
```

... I guess, because the variables are already declared `const` if I read that arrow correctly (or maybe because a section is already assumed to be "kept")? So attribute `keep` is definitely not the answer here ...

Comment: `strings` doesn't work too well when trying to get a list of symbols or sections. I'd look at `readelf -a` output

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey - I originally observed this via `size -A --totals`, I just liked `strings` because it happened to dump both data and names in this example; otherwise I just tried the `...-readelf -a` for the ARM build, without vs with `-Wl,--gc-sections`, and there are no matches for section names when `-Wl,--gc-sections` is active, same as described in the OP.

Comment: If you can use gcc 11 or higher, try `__attribute__((retain))`. I didn't test it for ARM, but for x86_64 it works.

Comment: Thanks @dimich - my `gcc --version` is 12.2.0; `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version` is 10.1.0, but they both give me "warning: 'retain' attribute directive ignored" (regardless of use of `-Wl,--gc-sections`)

Answer (score 2):

To inform linker that some variable needs to be preserved you should use the `-Wl,--undefined=XXX` option:

```
gcc ... -Wl,--undefined=greeting
```

Note that `__attribute__((used))` is a compiler-only flag to suppress `-Wunused-variable` warning.

Comment: --undefined makes the respective symbol *undefined* in the linker's output, i.e., it does not have an address or contents associated with it. It does not prohibit the linker from removing the variable's contents but actually enforces it.

Answer (score -1):

OK - I found something; not ideal, but at least its just a "syntax hack", and I don't have to come up with stupid stuff to do with the structs just so they show up in the executable (and usually even the code I come up with in that case, gets optimized away `:)`).

I first tried the `(void) varname;` hack used for [How can I suppress "unused parameter" warnings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599160/how-can-i-suppress-unused-parameter-warnings-in-c) - I left it below just to show it doesn't work.

What ended up working is: basically, just have a `static const void*` where the `main()` is, and assign a pointer to the struct to it (EDIT: ***in** the `main()`*!); I guess because of "static const", the compiler will not remove the variable and its section, even with `-Wl,--gc-sections`. So `test_opt.c` now becomes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_opt.h"

const char greeting[] = "Hello World - am used";

static const void *fake; //, *fakeB;

int main(void) {
  fake = &mystruct;
  (void) &mystring; //fakeB = &mystring;
  printf("%s!\n", greeting);
  return 0;
}
```

... and we can test with:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -g -Wl,--gc-sections test_opt.c mystruct.c -o test_opt.elf -lc -lnosys

$ arm-none-eabi-readelf -a ./test_opt.elf | grep -i 'mystring\|mystruct'
  [ 5] .MYSTRUCT         PROGBITS        00013780 013780 000024 00   A  0   0  4
   01     .init .text .fini .rodata .MYSTRUCT .ARM.exidx .eh_frame
     5: 00013780     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 .MYSTRUCT
   379: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS mystruct.c
   535: 00013780    36 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 mystruct

$ arm-none-eabi-strings ./test_opt.elf | grep -i 'mystring\|mystruct'
*myStructer here
mystruct.c
MyStruct_t
mystruct
MyStruct
mystruct.c
mystring
mystruct.c
mystruct
.MYSTRUCT
```

Note that only `mystruct` in above example ended up being preserved - `mystring` still got optimized away.

---

EDIT: note that if you try to cheat and move the assignment outside of main:

```c
static const void *fake = &mystruct, *fakeB = &mystring;

int main(void) {
...
```

... then the compiler will see through your shenanigans, and greet you with:

```
test_opt.c:6:39: warning: 'fakeB' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
    6 | static const void *fake = &mystruct, *fakeB = &mystring;
      |                                       ^~~~~
test_opt.c:6:20: warning: 'fake' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
    6 | static const void *fake = &mystruct, *fakeB = &mystring;
      |                    ^~~~
```

... and you're none the better off still.