# why linker does not strip main routine from executable?

Tags: linker, program-entry-point

I tested two successfully exiting minimal programs, first uses `libc`, second does not use `libc`.

First:

```
    segment .text
    global main
main:
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Build and check size:

```
yasm -f elf64 main.s; clang -o main main.o; stat ./main
...
Size: 8552
...
```

Second:

```
    segment .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall
```

Build and check size:

```
yasm -f elf64 main.s; ld -o main main.o; stat ./main
...
Size: 704
---
```

Obviously program using *main* is larger in size.
Why linkers does not strip *main* routine from binaries to optimise for size? I mean linkers that get object files after compilation of C program.

Comment: What do you mean? I was asking about the possibility to "cut" code from main and paste it to _start, so that main will not be called.

Comment: It was meant as a joke. Sry, for having missed the ";-)".

Comment: I don't see any C code. Did you inspect the **contents**? Concluding from the size of a binary what happens internally is a really bad approach. There is no function/"routine" in your Assembler code! Just a label which generates a symbol.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827157/what-does-keep-mean-in-a-linker-script/9830185#9830185 why main is kept for the --gc-sections case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why linker does not strip main routine from executable?

Because linkers in general do not strip *any* routines from the object files they are given. They are simply not in that business.

Linkers do not operate on routines, they operate on *sections*. Some linkers can do limited removal of *unreferenced* sections, e.g. GNU BFD ld and Gold have `--gc-sections` flag, but in your example there are no unreferenced sections, so nothing would be GC'd anyway.

Now, the difference between your two programs is that the one with `main` links in C runtime startup (usually `crt0.o`), and sets up `argc` and `argv` arguments the way `main` is defined to expect them.

Your `main` doesn't care about this, but it would take a really smart linker to deduce that. Also, your `main` *does* care about calling `sys_exit` after returning, so it actually needs `crt0.o` for proper shutdown.

> Is is that argc/argv setting-up process, that takes up few kilobytes?

If you are using GNU ld, you can ask the linker to tell you *exactly* what's using how much space with the linker `--print-map` argument.

On ELF platforms, you can also use `nm main` to see which symbols are taking up space in the final binary, and use `ld -y <symbol> ...` to see where these symbols are getting linked from.

Comment: Is is that argc/argv setting-up process, that takes up few kilobytes?