# Is there a way to prevent an added .o file section of being removed from gnu linker garbage collection?

Tags: c++, linker, arm, gnu, ld

I have an asymmetric dual core (ARM) controller (A5 core and M4 core).
I want to create ONE binary which I can write into the RAM/ROM of the controller and then execute code for both cores.
I include the M4 code as a .o file in the A5 linker ld. The section is garbage collected because of the option `--gc-sections`. Is there a way how I can keep this section but still use the option `--gc-sections` for all the other sections?

More detailed:

I built the m4 code and from the binary output I create a .o file.

```
COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe -O binary --gap-fill 0xff m4_tester.elf m4_tester.bin
COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm m4_tester.bin m4_tester.o
```

This file I included in the A5 project linker .ld file as a section:

```
    SECTIONS
    {  
      .m4stuff : { 
        . = ALIGN(4);
        m4_tester.o
        KEEP(*(.m4stuff))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        } > m4code

    ...
    }
```

So far this works all fine and looks like this in the map file:

```
.m4stuff        0x3f4e0000      0xd68
                0x3f4e0000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
 m4_tester.o()
 .data          0x3f4e0000      0xd68 m4_tester.o
                0x3f4e0000                _binary_m4_tester_bin_start
                0x3f4e0d68                _binary_m4_tester_bin_end
 *(.m4stuff)
                0x3f4e0d68                . = ALIGN (0x4)
```

Now I would also like to use the linker option `--gc-sections`. By its definition the m4stuff section is now garbage collected:

```
.m4stuff        0x3f4e0000        0x0
                0x3f4e0000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
 m4_tester.o()
 *(.m4stuff)
                0x3f4e0000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
```

Is there a way how I can keep this section but still use the option `--gc-sections` for all the other sections?

Comment: This [Include binary in ld script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327609/include-binary-file-with-gnu-ld-linker-script) questions has some other ways to do this which might avoid 'KEEP' and be more appropriate to the use case (for the poster or others who might look here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle the KEEP command in your command file should do this.

From the [GNU ld manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Keep.html):

> 3.6.4.4 Input Section and Garbage Collection
>
> When link-time garbage collection is in use (‘--gc-sections’), it is often useful to mark
> sections that should not be eliminated. This is accomplished by
> surrounding an input section’s wildcard entry with KEEP(), as in
> KEEP(*(.init)) or KEEP(SORT_BY_NAME(*)(.ctors)).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827157/what-does-keep-mean-in-a-linker-script) contains an example of KEEP use that might help.

Comment: I figured now out it works when I add `KEEP(*(.data))` instead of the `KEEP(*(.m4stuff))`

Answer (score 0):

After Jeremy correctly said that the KEEP command should do what I asked for, I checked how I used KEEP wrong.

I realized that the data in the `m4_tester.o` is actually marked as `.data` section and that this is done by the `arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe`.

By using  `KEEP(*(.data))` instead of the `KEEP(*(.m4stuff))` it works:

```
    SECTIONS
    {  
      .m4stuff : { 
        . = ALIGN(4);
        m4_tester.o
        KEEP(*(.data))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        } > m4code

    ...
    }
```

I also figured out that i can rename the section with the option `--rename-section` for `arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe`

With this I can rename the section to a more unique name:

```
COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm --rename-section .data=.m4data m4_tester.bin m4_tester.o
```

Now I can use this in the linker file:

```
    SECTIONS
    {  
      .m4stuff : { 
        . = ALIGN(4);
        m4_tester.o
        KEEP(*(.m4data))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        } > m4code

    ...
    }
```

The map file shows then:

```
.m4stuff        0x3f4e0000     0x8000
                0x3f4e0000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
 m4_tester.o()
 .m4data        0x3f4e0000     0x8000 m4_tester.o
                0x3f4e0000                _binary_m4_tester_bin_start
                0x3f4e8000                _binary_m4_tester_bin_end
 *(.m4data)
                0x3f4e8000                . = ALIGN (0x4)
```