# Creating a variable under specific section

Tags: c, gcc, linker, mingw, linker-scripts

I'm using linker `.ld` file to create a section called `SECVAR`

```
  .SECVAR : {
    *(.SECVAR )
  }
```

using the below command in my `.c` file to create a variable called `Dummy` under section:

```
unsigned short Dummy __attribute__((section(".SECVAR")))
```

After compiling it by using MinGW compiler the generated `output.map` file has no variable called `Dummy` under the section name `SECVAR`

How to correctly create a variable under section?

Comment: Try using the `KEEP` keyword in the linkerscript. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33013557/9439683